# What is the "hourly" in the amazon RedHat AMI names? Eg RHEL-6.5_GA-x86_64-7-Hourly2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

More generally, are there patterns to the naming conventions in community AMIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not any set patterns. Some vendors whom release multiple AMI's may adopt some kind of pattern to differentiate between each of them.

I suspect in the case of Redhat, the options exist due to the way its licensed. Its a non-free linux distribution that has a higher hourly rate than most other distributions. If you already have a Redhat Enterprise subscription, you can use that instead of paying the increased hourly rate.